# Case changing and detecting with expl3 that works for all engines

Tags: pdftex, unicode, expl3, cases

As noted in `interface3.pdf`, commands such as `\str_case_e:nn` are engine-related. Thus

```
\str_case_e:nnF {\text_titlecase:n {a}} { {A} {true} } {false}
```

will result in `true` for all engines, while

```
\str_case_e:nnF {\text_titlecase:n {\`a}} { {\`A} {true} } {false}
```

will be `false` for all engines, and

```
\str_case_e:nnF {\text_titlecase:n {à}} { {À} {true} } {false}
```

will be `false` for pdflatex and `true` for unicode engines.

When writing a package, I need a reliable way to change and detect text cases that works for all engines. The input may be in the form of normal letters (`Aa`), letters with accents in macros (like `\'a`) or with unicode (like `Àà`). If there are no unified method, I would also like to know if there are separate ones for different engines.

---

*Motivation:
This question is for the package [crefthe](https://ctan.org/pkg/crefthe). For now the command `\Crefthe` does not work properly due to this issue.*

Comment: I'm wondering about your use case: you seem to be using text functions for something that looks programmatic.

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks for pointing this out. I'm not familiar enough with expl3 and the code is obtained by trial and error, certainly better implements exist.

Comment: Just in case you didn't know... the documentation for expl3 is at `texdoc interface3` and others. — I think the Unicode normalization rules are implemented in expl3 instead of being built-in so in theory it should be possible without unacceptable runtime overhead... but if the expl3 code currently does not support it you'd have to implement it yourself.